# jquery toggle class not working fully

Tags: jquery, class, toggle, thumbnails

This even is suppose to move a div by adding the class down to it. But it moves to early?
.title has not hit the top and its already on the go!?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).scroll(function() {
    var moveit = $('.title'), //the titles are to move
        targetScroll = $('.title').position().top, //when .title is at top
        currentScroll = $(document.body).scrollTop();

    moveit.toggleClass('down', currentScroll >= targetScroll);
  });
});

#box #left ul li:hover .down {
  top: 500px;
}
```

.down gets included way to early.

What am I doing wrong... It's staring me in the face isn't it?

Comment: Your code works: http://jsfiddle.net/RVbCq/ it is more than likely a css problem.

Answer (score 0):

That is because jQuery uses it own queues to handle animations. It just steps to the next line. If you want to know when scrolling is finished, it is probably best to use the `scrollTo` plugin: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

This will let you enter a function that is executed when done scrolling. Use the `onAfter` parameter in the hash object.

**UPDATE**

I hope I found it. You are checking against `document.body`. The scroll value is always 0 of the body. So please check against: `$(document).scrollTop()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/RVbCq/1/

Comment: Reading more carefully through your code. I don't know if my reasons are correct. Your code is a bit messy with all the commas and predefined queries. But I hope that the plugin will do the work for you, so I leave the answer here.

Comment: I changed it from position to offset and it works. Although I'm not quite sure why.